# RoundingMode HALF_UP is not working properly

Tags: java, rounding, decimalformat

From my understand, RoundingMode.HALF_UP uses our tradition style of rounding. However, it is not giving me the desired results:

I'm using DecimalFormat() with different parameters(#, #.#, ... etc) and inputting the double 3.5545

```
// taken from Util    
public static void setRound(int a)      // Set rounding decimal places
{
    roundTo = a;

    String t = "#";
    if (roundTo > 0)
    {
        t += ".";
        for (int u = 1; u <= roundTo; u++)
            t += "#";
    }

    df = new DecimalFormat(t);
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}

public static String round(double d)    // Rounds up answers to set place
{
    return df.format(d);
}

// taken from Testing class
 for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
    Util.setRound(a);
    System.out.println(Util.round(3.5545));
    }

// results
0 -> 4              
1 -> 3.6   
2 -> 3.55   
3 -> 3.554 *(I want 3.555)*  
4 -> 3.5545
```

How would I be able to fix this issue (any number trailed by 5 rounds up)? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: I have put in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BigDecimal scale method like ;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal("3.5545").setScale(i, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            System.out.println(bg);
        }
```

Output ;

```
0 --> 4
1 --> 3.6
2 --> 3.55
3 --> 3.555
4 --> 3.5545
```

Comment: Note that `new BigDecimal(3.5545).toString()` returns `3.55449999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [java 8 bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915) related to this that may or may not be fixed in your version of java.